# Proximity alerts not triggered, starting with recent Android version

Tags: android, location, proximity

From at least 2015 to early 2019, the following code worked well;
but starting some time in 2019, it stopped working.
I can't say when, because I was not working on the code throughout 2019
due to health issues.
I have an old Samsung S5 running Android 6.0. The code works on it.
I have a Samsung S9 running Android 9.0. The code fails on it.
I can't run on Android 7 or 8, so I can't tell when it started to fail.

The code does the following:
Method setupProximityAlerts registers ProxReceiver.
Then it fetches from a database desired waypoint locations;
and calls method addProximityAlert for each.
It makes an implicit intent, retrieves a Broadcast pendingIntent for it,
and sends the pending Intent to mLocationManager.addProximityAlert.
Now, the waypoints are all registered to trigger/fire a broadcast
when the device approaches any waypoint.

```
    mProxReceiver = new ProxReceiver( );
    IntentFilter sFilter = new IntentFilter( "dkr.ajijic.apps.tm.PROX_ALERT" );
    mContext.registerReceiver( mProxReceiver, sFilter );
    mMediaCursor = tmProviderUtils.getWaypointCursor(trkId, 0, 10000);
    if (mMediaCursor.getCount() <= 1) return false;
    if (mMediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
       addProximityAlert(mMediaCursor);
    }
    while (mMediaCursor.moveToNext());
    ...
    private void addProximityAlert( MediaCursor mMediaCursor) {
    getWaypointProperties(mMediaCursor);
    Intent intent = new Intent( "dkr.ajijic.apps.tm.PROX_ALERT" );
    PendingIntent proxPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
          mContext, wptId, intent, 0);
    ...
    mLocationManager.addProximityAlert( latitude, longitude, proxRadius, -1L, proxPendingIntent );
    }
```

The following code (in a ForeGround Service) sends each GPS fix to LocationManager.

```
       private void onLocationChangeUnFilter(final Location location ) {
   if(location == null) return;
   if(googleLocationListener != null)
   googleLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
```

I know it works, because as I walk the location-cursor moves along over a map.
When I approach a waypoint, method ProxReceiver.onReceive should receive a broadcast. 
The problem is: LocationManager no longer broadcasts.

As a test, I coded AlarmManager to broadcast one of the pendingIntents,
and ProcReceiver.onReceive did indeed receive the broadcast.
This means the problem isn't in the intent or pendingIntent.
So, I'm quite sure the problem lies in LocationManager.

Just to cover the bases:
Here's the relevant manifest code.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".tour.ProxReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="dkr.ajijic.apps.tm.PROX_ALERT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I've read through the Google release documents for Android 7, 8 , and 9.
I've read several dozen stackOverflow question/responses.
I've looked for recent articles, examples, tutorials, etc.
All to no avail.
If anybody can help, I would certainly appreciate it!